# Using distinct() function in list. distinct function is not working in list

Tags: python, django, django-views, distinct

I am building a Blog App AND I am filtering many queries in one view. I mean, I am filtering two posts which are posted by `request.user` and `By request.user's friends`. AND `appending` all the filtered results in list. BUT when i `append` all the results then duplicate posts are showing in browser.
Then i used **distinct()** function in list then the error is showing :-

> 'list' object has no attribute 'distinct'

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,default='',null=True,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
    favourites = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='favourites ', blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def all_blogposts(request):
    ALL_POSTS = [].distinct()

#Adding user's post in the list.
    user_post = BlogPost.objects.filter(favourites =request.user)[:5]

    for post in user_post:
        ALL_POSTS.append(post)

#Adding friend's post in the list.

    all_posts = BlogPost.objects.all()
    requested = request.user.profile.friends.all()

    for user_p in requested:
        for sets in user_p.user.blogpost_set.all():
            ALL_POSTS.append(sets)

    context = {'ALL_POSTS':ALL_POSTS}
    return render(request, 'all_posts.html', context)
```

When i use `distinct()` and check then the error is keep showing.

I also tried to use `distinct()` after `[:5]` in `user_post` but then it shows.

> Cannot create distinct fields once a slice has been taken.

Many Duplicate posts are showing.

Any help would be Much Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your list is

```
>>> mylist = [1,1,2,3,3,4,5]
>>> print(mylist)
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
>>> mylist = list(set(mylist))
>>> print(mylist)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Convert your list as a set and make it list again.

For your problem you can take a new array and can do it:

```
new_array = []
for post in ALL_POSTS:
    if post not in new_array:
        new_array.append(post)
```

It will give you unique posts.

Comment: I did by adding `new_list = list(set(ALL_POSTS))` BUT now nothing is showing.

Comment: A set does *not* retain the order of the elements, only for *small* ints it will guarantee the order since then the hash functions works with an identity function.

Comment: @Mack will you please show what have in your ALL_POSTS through printing. Also, did you add this code just before context?

Comment: It Worked, Thank You Very Much . BUT i have a question, Won't be this slower in big data ?

Comment: @Mack not so much. depending on the server per second about `10^7 to 10^9` operations execute. if you have 10000000 posts in the `ALL_POSTS` list it would take 1 second. But you can simplify models and query for more efficiency.

Comment: Thank You very Much, Can you tell me a little , How can i simplify `models and query` ?

Comment: @Mack showing friends' posts is a complex task. I am describing you a senario, firstly you have to show today's posts of friends then next day... again which friend's post do you like most that be a factor for the query. besides that post you have read already why you will see it again at the top? that can be a factor.